# Malaysian visa for holder of Singapore TEP

Tags: visas, singapore, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm a Sri Lankan working under a training employment pass in Singapore. My pass is valid till 22 March 2017. Last month I applied for a Malaysian visa and was granted a multiple entry visa valid for 4 months starting from November 4th 2016.
Even though my pass is valid till March my training period ends and I'll be heading back to Sri Lanka on 5th January 2017. I have booked the flight. I expect my employer will cancel my pass before that.

[This](http://www.kln.gov.my/web/sgp_singapore/requirement_foreigner) document states that my long term pass must have a 3 month validity from the expected date of entry to Malaysia.

My question is, can I visit Malaysia and come back to Singapore on 2nd of January, and enter Malaysia on the transit of my flight home?

Comment: TEP pass is valid for multiple entries?

Comment: @pnuts 5th of January 2017.

Comment: @AliAwan yeah pass is valid for multiple entries. But I've heard when the end of employment period approaches, they cancel the pass and issue a normal visit pass for the remaining time.

Comment: That means when you will leave singapore , you pass would not be valid? is that you mean

Comment: @AliAwan I suspect that will be the case. I couldn't still verify what happens when/if they cancel the pass before employment period ends.

Comment: If they cancel the pass then you would need a singapore visa to reenter as a sri lankan citizen

Comment: @pnuts Training period ending is flexible. My employer told me I have to collect my last pay cheque on 4th of January  after looking at my flight itinerary. I hope to report to work until 4th, with the exception of 2nd. (To go to Malaysia and come back).

Comment: @AliAwan Yeah but they have to keep the pass valid until 4th right? As I have to be employed there until that day? At least that's my understanding because if they cancel the TEP before that I'm no longer eligible to be employed under the short term visit pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate issues here.

First, **will Singapore let you back in?** This will depend on what happens to your training pass.  If it's still valid, you'll have no problems;  but if it's cancelled,  you will be granted a Short Term Visit Pass, which is single-entry and **will not allow you to return to Singapore**.  So I suggest you negotiate with your employer to ensure they don't cancel the pass early.

Second, **will Malaysia let you in**?   Here the answer in practice is **yes**, because you already have a valid visa and they have no way of knowing the original conditions have changed.  Now you may be asked how long you're staying in Malaysia, and your visa for returning to Singapore checked, but as long as you have a valid visa and a flight ticket out it's highly unlikely they will care (or even know) about the 3-months-beyond stipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. This cleared all but 1 doubt. So for 1, I can check with my employer and know for sure if TEP will be active until 4th of January. For 2, there's gonna be a small issue because my visit to Malaysia will consist of a combination  of taxis and walking. (No return ticket to show.). I can book a Malaysia -> Singapore bus and show that at my entry to Malaysia but I'm not sure if that'll be valid.

Comment: @chamod I meant your return ticket to Sri Lanka, which shows that you're not planning to stay in Malaysia.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense!